# Creation own JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I use a JPanel with GridLayout and I put `JLabel` inside. Everithing works. But I want to use my own class (extends `JLabel`) there is a problem.

When I use a `JLabel` I have this rendering:

[image: result]

And when I use my own `JLabel` I have that:

[image: result]

Here is my code from my `JLabel` custom :

```
public class LabelCustom extends JLabel{

int x;
int y;

public LabelCustom(int x, int y) {
    super();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.setBackground(Color.white);
    this.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.LOWERED));
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}
```

}

And how I use it :

```
JPanel j = new JPanel();
    j.setLayout(new GridLayout(nbCaseY, nbCaseX));

    for(int i=0; i<nbCaseY; i++) {
        HashMap<Integer, JLabel> ligne = new HashMap();
        for(int y=0; y<nbCaseX; y++) {
            LabelCustom p = new LabelCustom(i, y);
            p.addMouseListener(ml);
            //p.setBounds(100+ y*(hauteur), 100 + i*( hauteur), hauteur, hauteur);
            p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(hauteur, hauteur));

            //p.setBounds(100+ y*( (width-200-2*hauteur)/nbCaseX), 100 + i*( (height-200)/nbCaseY), ((width-200-2*hauteur)/nbCaseX), ((height-200)/nbCaseY));
            p.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("icon"));
            p.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.LOWERED));

            p.setOpaque(true);
            p.setVisible(true);
            j.add(p);
            ligne.put(y, p);
        }
        Frame.p.getListeNiveau().get(0).ajouterLigne(ligne);
    }
```

Comment: `JLabel` already has `get/X/Y` methods, best not to re-implement them, unless you have a very good reason

Comment: It's not for x and y position. It is for an id of hashmap, i think it is useful ;)

Comment: You might, be how do you think the API is determining the position of your component?  I bet if you added `@Override` to both the `getX` and `getY` methods, it would still compile, telling you that you are overriding methods of the parent class, methods it probably wants to use for some purpose ... like position the component ... maybe

Comment: If you need some kind of ID, id create s new method, maybe called ID, which takes a particular object, maybe a Point in this case and use that instead

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Yes indeed methods getX and getY already exist. With others name, it works thank you

Comment: *"thank you"* Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. BTW MadProgrammer, are you going to write up an answer for this question?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Do I really have to, isn't there a duplicate somewhere :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"Do I really have to.."* No, not at all. I just thought I'd issue the prompt before advising the OP to either write up their own answer or delete the question. *"isn't there a duplicate somewhere"* Probably, but I wouldn't know what to search on, to locate it / them. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JLabel` already has a `getX` and `getY` method which is to position the label on the screen, you've (unwittingly) overridden this functionality and are now returning unrelated information.

> It's not for x and y position. It is for an id of hashmap, i think it is useful ;)

So, instead of using `getX/Y`, I suggest making a `ID` class, which carries the information you need (possibly overriding the `equals` and `hashcode` methods to make it easier to do comparisons) and using that instead (providing a `getID` and `setID` methods)